# Grouping rows of data in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a set of data:

```
 Project<-c("1","2","3","4","5")
 Product<-c("A","B","A","B","B")
 data<-data.frame(Product, Project)

 > data
   Product Project
         A       1
         B       2
         A       3
         B       4
         B       5
```

I want to group the data such that it becomes:

```
    Product Project
       A       1,3
       B       2,4,5
```

May I ask how can I do this in R?  I was looking up the apply function but still couldn't figure out how I can do this.....  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `aggregate(.~Product,data,FUN=c)` or `aggregate(.~Product,data,FUN=toString)`, depending how you want the `Project` column.

Comment: Thanks!  Can you post on answer and I will accept

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(Product) %>%
  summarise(Project = paste(Project, collapse = ','))
## A tibble: 2 x 2
#  Product Project
#   <fctr>   <chr>
#1       A     1,3
#2       B   2,4,5
```